# How to search html file for css reference without FQDN and add it?

Tags: html, bash, sed, scripting

I am trying to write a bash script that will search inside given HTML file, locate if there are any CSS Style reference without the FQDN and add it in-line.

For example:

I have an HTML file with the following code:

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.domain/css/main.css"; />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wraper_page.cs " />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Menu.Skin" />
```

---

So I want the script to cover all option all over the document (Ignore the existing http reference | add FQDN for the missing one | take in consider also the ".cs" file).
And also - If I want to use a variable for my FQDN? using $1 for example? 
So I'll run the script as follow: './myscript.sh my.domain'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
sed -E '\|type="text/css"| s|href="(my.domain)?/?|href="my.domain/|' data
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended **`bash`** + **`xmlstarlet`** solution:

Sample `input.html` file:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.domain/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wraper_page.cs " />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Menu.Skin" />
</html>
```

---

**`add_domain_to_url.sh`** script:

```
#!/bin/bash

domain="$1"
xmlstarlet ed -O -L -u "//link[not(starts-with(@href, '$domain'))]/@href" -x "concat('$domain/', .)" "$2"
```

---

Signature: `bash add_domain_to_url.sh <domain_name> <filepath>`

---

Usage:

```
bash add_domain_to_url.sh "my.domain" input.html
```

The final `input.html` contents:

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.domain/css/main.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.domain/css/main2.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.domain/css/wraper_page.cs "/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.domain/css/Menu.Skin"/>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried that. I used apt-get to install xmlstarlet and try your script. It gives a lot of output but changed nothing... :\